# Want to send email through wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

I am new to wordpress, I just installed wordpress on my godaddy server. I want to create a form on wordpress page where user will enter the details, name and password. when the user clicks on submit button of form, I want wordpress to send me an email with the details entered by user in the form. Please help me with this.

Comment: do you have some code ?, can you say what would be the fields on the form ?

Comment: I created a page in wordpress and entered this code, I want to use this and php to get email of the data entered by user 
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm"> <div>

<div>Name</div> 
<div><input id="name" type="text" name="nm" /></div>
<div>Email 
<div><input id="email" type="text" name="email" /></div> 

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></div> </div> </form>

Comment: please edit your question with your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to use a plugin. There are many plugins that help you create contact forms that would also send you an email with the details.
[Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) is simple to set up and use.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @kat_indo, I wrote some custom code to achieve the results, but your answer suits in most conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use wp_mail() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: Thanks prakhar19 for the link. I am a bit confused. I know how to create page in wordpress, I can put the form code for getting the user data, where should the code for wp_mail be added? I know it might be a simple step, but since I am new to wordpress, can you please let me know. Really appreciate all the help :)

Comment: You should just add wp_mail() in the php file which processes the form submission request.

Comment: In case of wordpress page where will this php file be?

Comment: I created a page in wordpress and entered this code, I want to use this and php to get email of the data entered by user
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
<div>
<div>Name</div> <div><input id="name" type="text" name="nm" /></div>
<div>Email <div><input id="email" type="text" name="email" /></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></div>
</div>
</form>

Answer (score 1):

There are some plugins, not sure if you want that. But if you don't you can do it on your own.

If you want to do it by yourself:

This is the file that gets called by the request (usually an AJAX request):

```
<?php 

$client_email = $_POST["user_email"];
$client_email = (string) $client_email;
include('Mail.php');

$recipients = 'email@gmail.com';  
$headers['From']    = 'from@gmail.com'; 
$headers['To'] = 'email@gmail.com';
$headers['Subject'] = "subject";
$body = "This is the content" ;

// Define SMTP Parameters
$params['host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$params['port'] = '465';
$params['auth'] = 'PLAIN';
$params['username'] = 'from@gmail.com';
$params['password'] = 'yourpassword';

//$params['debug'] = 'true';

// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

// Send the message
$mail->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

---

**Notes**:

- I used PEAR mail. So I could test it from my local computer.(http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download)
  I download it manually (PEAR Mail-1.2.0.tgz)
  And then install it (http://code.rawlinson.us/2012/02/install-php-pear-on-windows-7.html)
  I move the contents of the .tgz to /PHP/pear, just move it there, and somehow it worked !
  It was giving me an error, so I installed Net_SMTP (pear install Net_SMTP)